# Axios still returning data after using AbortController in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, abortcontroller

all, I'm trying to understand what is off about my code involving cancelling an axios post request. I have a form via which a user can make a request for an openai search for movies. While the search is going on, I present the user with a cancel button to abort the search and enter a new search term. When I test, if I abort the request, I still receive the data and it is still processed as if the request were not cancelled.

This is happening in a React component I have devoted to handling the openai request. Per my package.json, I'm using Axios 9.5.0. The first thing I do inside the component is set a state, and then:

```
  const controller = new AbortController();
```

Here is the handler for when the user submits a search:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    (set some states to set up correct user interface)

    try {
      const searchResults = await axios.post(
        "/api/movies/ai-search",
        {
          userRequest: request,
        },
        { signal: controller.signal }
      );
      const jsonResults = JSON.parse(searchResults.data);
      
      (do stuff with the returned data)
      
    } catch (err) {
      if (axios.isCancel(err)) {
        console.log("Request cancelled");
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
      
      (set some more states to reflect error message)

      );
    }
  };
```

And here is the handler for when the user clicks to cancel the current search:

```
  const handleSearchCancel = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    // handler for when user cancels search
    console.log("Cancelling the search") // confirm I made it to the handler
    controller.abort();
    
    (set a couple of states to update the UI)
  };
```

One problem I thought might be the case is all the state setting: most of them are prop-drilled from the parent component. Might that be causing the problem? Anyway, if I submit a search and then cancel it, I do get the console log that I'm in the right handler. But if I wait a few more moments, the search results do come in and are handled as if the request wasn't cancelled.

EDIT:

Per Dat's suggestion, I've switched to a `useRef` setup:

```
  const abortControllerRef = useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController());
```

That worked for the first search...but all subsequent searches are immediately cancelled without user input. In researching this, it seems that I need to instantiate a new AbortController for each request. BUT since I am using useRef, I can't do that within the click handler. Going to try to do it in a custom hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Can you check your Axios's version again ? Axios 9.5.0 doesn't exist.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by that as well. In my package.json I have `axios: "^1.6.7"` but when I do `npm -v axis` on the command line I get back 9.5.0.

Comment: I guest you "(set some states to set up correct user interface)" made the controller in request and in handleCancel are different. So can you try
```const abortControllerRef = useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController());``` or ```const abortControllerRef = useMemo(()=> {return new AbortController()},[])```

Comment: Dat, to make sure I am understanding correctly, useRef keeps its value if a changed state produces a re-render, so by putting the new AbortController into a ref, then it isn't re-initialized. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: That's right, the main target is keeping both controller are the same.

Comment: That worked, part of the way! When I cancel the request (`abortControllerRef.current.abort();`) it cancels, I get the appropriate "request cancelled" log entry. BUT...if I submit another search, it is immediately cancelled without user interaction.

Comment: And about your confusion about version of axios. The command ```npm -v axis``` return version of npm. You can try other package name, it alway return 9.5.0. So if you want to check version of a package, you should use ```sudo npm view axios version``` or ```npm view axios version```

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Because the attribute aborted is true now. You can see the picture I have added in my answer that captured from axios package. 
So it can solve by declaring the ref is null. After that, when you sent a request, make it become ```abortControllerRef = useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController());```. Finally, when you cancel the request, make it become null again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257015/discussion-between-lkalliance-and-dat-huynh).

Answer (score 0):

OK, with Dat's help we figured it out.

1. useRef did its job correctly: I could utilize it to make a reference to an AbortController:

`const abortRef = useRef<AbortController>(new AbortController())`

and I could reference it in the `cancelSearchHandler` function. BUT...once I did that, then the search is PERMANENTLY aborted. All subsequent searches absent a refresh were automatically cancelled. So...

2. Re-instantiate a new AbortController on search submit. EXCEPT I could not do that inside the submit handler. Cannot use React hooks inside of handlers, they have to live at the top level of the component. So "we" finally got the answer...
3. Forget the React hooks, use standard JavaScript to instantiate the controller, but do it OUTSIDE the component (brilliant, Dat!). Same module, just outside the component. So:

```
let controller: AbortController;
```

That was outside the component, which made it equally available to both the submit handler and the cancel handler. Then use it normally.